# center caption with subimage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I have the following image:[image]
Produced from the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, trim=5cm 5cm 5cm 5cm]{images/det.pdf}
    \caption{Deterministic algorithms}
  \label{fig:fingonly1}
        \end{subfigure}%
        ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc.
          %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, trim=5cm 5cm 5cm 5cm]{images/pro.pdf}
  \caption{Probabilistic algorithms}
  \label{fig:fingonly2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Average positioning error for the non-dynamic indoor positioning system}\label{fig:rssi}
\end{figure}
```

I want to center the text with the image. 
any recommendations on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you producing the images using `pgfplots`? if so, you could pass `trim axis` options to `tikzpicture`, as in 
`\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]...\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: I am using \usepackage{graphicx}, not pgfplots, any recommendations on how to fix it with graphicx

Comment: I meant to produce the plot bars, not to include them. Or are they just -pdf files you already have?

Comment: I made them on excel and then I export them as PDF, I use trim to remove the white space created from excel in the chart.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8188dbrja4w83a7/1det.pdf
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qi98wqelgbretuw/1prob.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your images are not centered inside the `subfigure` environments and that the total length for both images will be greater than `\textwidth`.

I used `\centering` inside each `subfigure` environment; I also reduced the subfigure width to half `\textwidth` and removed extra spaces between them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, trim=5cm 5cm 5cm 5cm]{1det}
  \caption{Deterministic algorithms}
  \label{fig:fingonly1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, trim=5cm 5cm 5cm 5cm]{1prob}
  \caption{Probabilistic algorithms}
  \label{fig:fingonly2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Average positioning error for the non-dynamic indoor positioning system}
\label{fig:rssi}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Try not to use `[!h]` as placement specifier; either use a not so restrictive option or, even better, not use any at all.